# Refactor loop for into stream in android

Tags: java, android, java-stream

I want to refactor my for loops into streams:

```
for (TrackingGroup item : trackingGroups) {
    List<IItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
    items.add(new ItemText(getActivity().getString(R.string.track_title) + " " + trackingGroup.getTitle()));
    for (ProfileAnswerItem answerItem : listofAnswers) {
        for (TrackingItem trackingItem : item.getItems()) {
            if (trackingItem.getId() == answerItem.getId()) {
                ItemQuestionResult itemView = new ItemQuestionResult(new ItemAnswer(item.getId(), answerItem.getId(), answerItem.getText(), false, true),
                        items.size() > 1);
                items.add(itemView);
               // adapter.add(itemView);
            } else {
                if (item.getId() == answerItem.getTrackId() && answerItem.isCustom()) {
                    ItemQuestionResult itemView = new ItemQuestionResult(new ItemAnswer(item.getId(), answerItem.getId(), answerItem.getText(), false, true),
                            items.size() > 1);
                    if (answerItem.getId() != lastID) {
                        items.add(itemView);
                        //adapter.add(itemView);
                        lastID = answerItem.getId();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    adapter.add(items);
}
```

and this is what I have on this moment:

```
Stream.of(trackingGroups)
                .forEach(trackingGroup1 -> {
                    List<IItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
                    items.add(new ItemText(getActivity().getString(R.string.track_title) + " " + trackingGroup.getTitle()));
                    Stream.of(listofAnswers)
                            .forEach(profileAnswerItem -> {
                                Stream.of(trackingGroup1.getItems())
                                        .forEach(trackingItem -> {
                                            if (trackingItem.getId() == profileAnswerItem.getId()) {
                                                ItemQuestionResult itemView = new ItemQuestionResult(new ItemAnswer(trackingGroup1.getId(),
                                                        profileAnswerItem.getId(), profileAnswerItem.getText(), false, true),
                                                        items.size() > 1);
                                                items.add(itemView);
                                            } else {
                                                if (trackingGroup1.getId() == profileAnswerItem.getTrackId() && profileAnswerItem.isCustom()) {
                                                    ItemQuestionResult itemView = new ItemQuestionResult(new ItemAnswer(trackingGroup1.getId(),
                                                            profileAnswerItem.getId(), profileAnswerItem.getText(), false, true),
                                                            items.size() > 1);
                                                    if (profileAnswerItem.getId() != lastID) {
                                                        items.add(itemView);
                                                        lastID = profileAnswerItem.getId();
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                            });
                });
```

now I have a problem with variable `lastID`. For lambdas this variable should be final. How can I add missing part and after that add results in adapter?

Comment: There is no requirement to use streams instead of loops. Sometimes (like here), the code is way worse with streams. Why do you think you want to use streams here?

Comment: I agree with @AndyTurner, you *could* probably refactor this to take advantage of streams by using map/flatMap to go from your data objects to Views, but as written, there's nothing gained by using streams.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use streams here. [Streams are useful when defining sophisticated data processing queries.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html) They provide a compact yet expressive way to define sequential operations on the elements of the stream, like the example provided by Oracle:

```
List<Integer> transactionsIds = 
    transactions.stream()
                .filter(t -> t.getType() == Transaction.GROCERY)
                .sorted(comparing(Transaction::getValue).reversed())
                .map(Transaction::getId)
                .collect(toList());
```

Writing`.stream().forEach(...)` (or `Stream.of(...).forEach(...)`) is a code smell. You are constructing a stream and immediately deconstructing it into a regular iteration over the elements. A regular `for` or `for each` construction seems both easier and clearer here, unless you refactor the content of your loop bodies as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `lastID` variable as a class field. The class members can be accessed inside lambda block without making them `final`.

Comment: Or you can use a mutable wrapper like `AtomicInteger`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code leaves out a lot of details, but trying to understand what you are trying to accomplish, I cam up with this:

```
for (TrackingGroup item : trackingGroups)
{
    List<IItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

    items.add(new ItemText(getActivity().getString(R.string.track_title) + " " + trackingGroup.getTitle()));

    for (ProfileAnswerItem answerItem : listofAnswers)
    {
        // first, find out how many items to create
        long itemsToCreate = item.getItems()
                                 .stream()
                                 .filter(trackingItem -> trackingItem.getId() == answerItem.getId())
                                 .count();

        if (itemsToCreate < item.getItems().size() // not all trackingItems matched the answerItem 
            && item.getId() == answerItem.getTrackId() && answerItem.isCustom() // answer matches your original condition
        )
        {
            itemsToCreate++; // create 1 extra item
        }

        // second, create and add items
        Stream.generate(() -> new ItemQuestionResult(new ItemAnswer(item.getId(),
                                                                    answerItem.getId(),
                                                                    answerItem.getText(),
                                                                    false,
                                                                    true),
                                                     items.size() > 1))
              .limit(itemsToCreate)
              .forEach(items::add);
    }

    adapter.add(items);
}
```

If I understood your code correctly, and as far as I can see without knowing where `lastID`, `listofAnswers`, `trackingGroup`, and `trackingGroups` come from or what they are used for after, you do not need `lastID` at all.

You tried to add an extra item if a `ProfileAnswerItem` does not match **all** `TrackingItem`s. And lastID was used to make sure to only add **one** of those per `ProfileAnswerItem`.

This was quite hard to read at first, and I think you can simplify this by separating the test and the item creation as shown. This also makes it more obvious that the items created for the tracking items are the same as the extra ones. This part can also benefit from using streams. For the rest, trying to convert it to streams completely made it harder to read.

If I misinterpreted your code, let me know. And maybe you can make your example code a bit simpler for us to understand more easily. All those missing classes make it very hard to work on this withouth creating a lot of mock classes first.